# SELinuxのポリシーでallowされているファイルへのアクセスがdenyとなるのは何故ですか

Tags: centos, selinux

現在、SELinuxの勉強をしているのですが、どうしても腑に落ちないことがあるので教えて下さい。

CentOS7を使いhttpdのDocumentRootを変更し、SELiunxをEnforcingにしてブラウザよりWEBサーバにアクセスすると403エラーとなりアクセスできなくなります。
SELinuxを Permissive に変更するか、アクセス対象となるファイル(例えば: index.html)のラベルを"httpd_sys_content_t"に変更するとアクセスできるようになります。

さて、これはよく知られた動作であります。
しかしながら、よく確認すると不可解な点があります。

確認のため、関連する情報を確認しました。

対象となる index.html のラベルをみると次のとおりです。

```
$ ls -Z  /home/www/html
-rw-rw-r--. www www unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 /home/www/html/index.html
```

httpd のラベルは次のとおりです。

```
$ ps -eZ | grep httpd
system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0      7287 ?        00:00:00 httpd
```

SELinuxのポリシーを確認しますと、次のようになっていました。

```
$ sesearch --allow --source httpd_t --perm read --target user_home_t --class file
Found 1 semantic av rules:
   allow httpd_t user_home_type : file { ioctl read getattr lock open } ;
```

SELinuxのポリシーをみると、"httpd_t" は "user_home_type" ラベルを持ったオブジェクトにアクセスできる、と設定されているように見えます。

監査ログを確認してみると、つぎのようになっていました。

```
# ausearch -m avc
type=AVC msg=audit(1589269188.714:569): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=7289 comm="httpd" 
name="index.html" dev="dm-0" ino=50334142 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext =
unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

監査ログを読み解くと、「ラベル"httpd_t"をもつプロセス"httpd"が、ラベル"user_home_t"をもつファイル"index.html"を"{read}"しようとしたところを"deny"した」ということのように思えます。実際にサーバは403エラーを返します。

この動作は、先述したポリシーにてallowされているように見受けられるのですが、実際にはdenyされています。

なぜポリシーにてallowされている動作がdenyされているのでしょうか。

教えていただきますと幸いです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sesearch に **-C** オプションを付けてみてください。

```
# sesearch -C --allow --source httpd_t --perm read --target user_home_t --class file
Found 1 semantic av rules:
DT allow httpd_t user_home_type : file { ioctl read getattr lock open } ; [ httpd_read_user_content ]
```

このルールは `httpd_read_user_content` というブール値に紐付いていて、先頭の **D** は無効になっていることを示します。

`setsebool` コマンドで有効にします。
永続化するなら **-P** オプションを付けます。

```
# setsebool httpd_read_user_content on
# setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content on
```